# Command Line Interface for Node Package not found

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, npm, npm-install

I installed a node.js (I think) package using the `npm i -g [package]` command. This package ([MJML](https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml)) has a command line tool. According to their documentation, there should be a command line tool included in the package, but when i use the command `mjml demo.mjml` i get the error `-bash: mjml: command not found`
I've noticed that there is a separate CLI package which i've also installed, but I received the same error.

My question is: Is there a change I need to make to allow node packages to use command line tools?

I'm using OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: Can you verify it in in your PATH? I don't know where npm global package are installed on Mac, but it will be where you will find the executable.

Comment: Have you installed Node using Homebrew?

Comment: Try `find  /usr  /opt -iname mjml` to see where it is located then put the containing directory in your PATH, or use it with its full path, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/mjml`

Comment: @DrakaSAN: Yes, I can verify that it's installed with the global packages

Comment: @robertklep I did install node using Homebrew

Comment: @NoahManion I think that might be the problem, since the Homebrew-installed version of Node installs global packages in some strange location (`~/.npm-packages/` or something). I use the official Node installer for Mac myself (even though I also use Homebrew for other stuff); Node binaries end up in a well-known directory (`/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: Is it the only global package to act like that? If you go to it s installation folder, can you execute it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a silly question, but are you sure the package was successfully installed?

Sometimes you need to install global packages as an admin with `sudo npm install [package] -g`.

Comment: No, sudo should **not** be used with npm, and would lead to other problems down the line